# long long conversion into byte array

Tags: c++, c, arrays

i'm trying to get any datatype(actually long long) into an byte/char array and read it out again...but for any reason it works good with integers but not with long long?
results:
value: 15
channel: 4

```
int main(){

int chan=4;
char buffer1 [20];
long long time=20203023;

memcpy(buffer1, &time, sizeof(time));
printf("value: %lld\n", buffer1[0]);

    memcpy(&buffer1[8], &chan, sizeof(chan));
    printf("channel: %d\0", *(&buffer1[8]));

    return 0;
}
```

Solution:

printf is the bad guy here...I memcopy the content of the array back into an long long, and the value is interpreted well now

```
int main() {

    int chan = 22;
    char buffer1[20];
    long long times = 20203023;
    long long time_new = 0;

    memcpy(buffer1, &times, sizeof(times));

    memcpy(&time_new, buffer1, sizeof(times));
    printf("value: %lld\n", time_new);

    return 0;
}
```

result: value: 20203023

thank you!!!

Comment: Decide on whether you want to code in C or in C++, please.

Comment: What result do you expect, and what do you get?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP doesn't want to tell us which language this is, and it does matter.

Answer (score 1):

The program behaviour is undefined. The `printf` format specifier *must* match the types passed in. `buffer1[0]` is a `char` type, and `%lld` is for `long long`.

Your `memcpy` approach is fine though. `buffer1`, as an array, will occupy contiguous memory, so is well-placed to receive a copy of the memory associated with `time` or `chan`.

Comment: it has to? i can interpret an long as int also or not?
if thats the cause this should work?

long long times=20203023;
long long *time_cast=0;

memcpy(buffer1, &times, sizeof(times));
time_cast =buffer1[0];
printf("value: %lld\n", time_cast);

Comment: `time_cast =buffer1[0];` is well-defined if `time_cast` is sufficiently large to hold the data and `buffer1[0]` has been initialised. Both are true in your case. You have to be careful when writing code like this. Undefined constructs are often only a whisker away. Are you coding this in C, or C++? Do amend the question tags at some point.

Comment: but I give time_cast an address right? and the buffer is initialized right? why doesnt that work?
or even:
long_cast=(long long*)buffer1[0];

Comment: Neither C nor C++ permit that cast. It might work on some platforms. Other compilers might eat your cat. I think you should move this discussion to the chatroom.

Comment: Please note that memcpy will give you a result which is endianess dependent. To write portable code, you'll have to manually shift and mask each byte instead: `array[0] = (uint8_t)((my_long_long >> 24) & 0xFF); array[1] = (uint8_t)((my_long_long >> 16) & 0xFF );` and so on.